# VNC connection via SSH proxy machine

Tags: ssh, vnc, ssh-tunnel, firewall

I would like to make a VNC connection from home to a Windows machine at work. The Windows machine is not accessible from the outside, but there is a Linux box that does have port 22 open, so it would seem that this can be done.

I suspect it's just a command that "forwards" connections to port 22 on the Linux machine to the Windows machine? Just can't find an example that does exactly this though

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ssh -L 5902:[vnc host]:5901 [ssh host]

then: vncviewer localhost:2

from: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html

Comment: Beautiful answer: terse, precise, answers the question exactly, and well-referenced (though I fixed the link for you, which was slightly wrong).  Bravo!

Comment: I think something is missing. Is this command meant to run on the inbetween Linux box? Remember, only port 22 is open to the outside.

Comment: On the machine which is being used to connect to the ssh machine. you basically connect to the ssh server like normal, but with these flags on the command, and it'll let you connect to vnc @ localhost, by forwarding the port through the tunnel you just made by logging into the ssh server.

Comment: Got it. Ok, when I run ssh 2.2.2.2 -L 5902:localhost:5901 3.3.3.3, It authenticates but then I get the message "3.3.3.3: command not found"

Comment: sorry, total brain meltdown. Try ssh -L 5902:[vnc host]:5901 [ssh host]

Comment: need to make sure your account on the ssh server is not locked down to prevent port forwarding as well. may want to add : ssh -L 5902:[vnc host]:5901 [remoteuser]@[ssh host]

Comment: Great, it worked between 3 machines on the inside, so if I battle from outside it's another issue. Thanks!

Comment: Answer doesn't explain command at all and the link is broken. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115906/567978 for a StackExchange answer with good breakdown

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting from a Linux machine at home, you can simply use the '-via' flag on vncviewer, like this:

```
vncviewer host-at-work.corp.com -via user@ssh-host.corp.com
```

and you'll either get a) the SSH password prompt or b) direct login via keys, and once you've authenticated your SSH session, you should see the vncviewer password window as if you were on the local network.

For a good GUI application, look at Remmina:

http://remmina.sourceforge.net/

Remmia allows you to set-up a connection that uses an SSH tunnel through a bastion host.  I have used it in the past to do exactly what you're attempting.