# VNC proxy-jump, possibly with ssh

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I use VNC a lot on a specific machine.  But it's on a separate network that I can't reach directly.

```
+----------------+     +----------------+
| Linux          |     | Windows        |        +---------------+
| VNC client     |     | OpenSSH Server |        | Linux         |
|   192.168.1.100-------192.168.1.22    |        | VNC server    |
|                |     |      10.10.1.33----------10.10.1.44     |
+----------------+     |                |        |               |
                       +----------------+        +---------------+
```

Currently, I RDP to a windows machine which bridges the networks. From the rdp desktop, I launch a vnc client to the vnc-server. The windows machine in the middle runs OpenSSH.  Is there a way for me to use that so I can connect to the vnc-server directly?

My solutions for `ssh` and `scp` are currently:

```
ssh -J 192.168.1.22 10.10.1.44
scp -o=ProxyJump=192.163.1.22 10.10.1.44:file .
```

I'd prefer to leave the windows machine alone if possible and do this from the client side.  That's because I actually have lots of these Windows bridges, each with an independent 10.10.1.x network with lots of VNC servers on each network.
I'm using `vinagre` as a vnc client and `x11vnc` as the vnc server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VNC connection via SSH proxy machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/216991/vnc-connection-via-ssh-proxy-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a SSH connection, you just need to add a port forwarding:

```
ssh -J 192.168.1.22 -L 5990:127.0.0.1:5900 10.10.1.44
```

In `-L 5990:127.0.0.1:5900` the `5990`is an arbitrary port number for your local machine. You connect your VNC client to this port. The `127.0.0.1:5900` is the destination address and port. This assumes your VNC server runs on port 5900. The destination address `127.0.0.1` is from the point of view of the server, you can also replace it with `10.10.1.44`.

Comment: Using 127.0.0.1 here also allows binding the VNC server to that address, so it is reachable *only* by ssh port-forwarding, if that is desired. I use that for my VMs, that is really handy.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. https://serverfault.com/a/216994/64874 this one does, which in this case would be  `ssh -L 5990:10.10.1.44:5900 192.168.1.22`

Comment: @chx Then obviously you situation is less complicated if you don't need a jump host.

Comment: I do. Your version SSHs into the target specifying a jump host and building a tunnel on localhost, my version SSHs into the jump host and builds a tunnel using the target host.